# Table = Table vs Table.Data(Table)

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++, axapta

What is the difference between the two statements below?

```
newTable = orginalTable
```

or

```
newTable.data(originalTable)
```

I suspect there is a performance benefit to the .data() method as it is more commonly used in standard AX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
newTable = originalTable;
info(strfmt('%1 %2', newTable.recId, originalTable.recId);

newTable.data(originalTable);
newTable.insert();
info(strfmt('%1 %2', newTable.recId, originalTable.recId);
```

You'll see that the first statement just creates another one pointer to existing record.  The second one creates new copy of existing record.

Comment: +1. I'll add that if you don't want to copy system fields from one record to another but only fields carrying a functional meaning (i.e. fields you can see in the AOT), use buf2buf() instead of data().

Comment: ah okay, begs the question why its not called something obvious like .copy()